# Place Text in Chart-Canvas Area in ChartJS

Tags: asp.net-core, canvas, html5-canvas, chart.js

I created two x,y arrays and then performed two chart using these. I want to write some texts in only Chart red one. And I want to use (x,y) coordinates to determine text region.
I try to Chartjs Global plugin but it causes to writing text all charts. I demand texting only one chart.
I could not succeed in Chartjs mono Plugin in Script.
Please Help Me.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="w3-row">
        <div class="w3-col s3"><p></p></div>
        <div class="w3-col s6" align="center"><canvas id="myChart" height="120"></canvas></div>
        <div class="w3-col s3"><p></p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-row">
        <div class="w3-col s3"><p></p></div>
        <div class="w3-col s6" align="center"><canvas id="myTau" height="120"></canvas></div>
        <div class="w3-col s3"><p></p></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var xCoord = new Array(1997, 2003, 2005, 2009, 2014, 2018, 2019);
    var yCoord = new Array(1, 3, 5, 3, 6, 10, 9);
    var c = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < xCoord.length; i++) {
        var obj = { x: xCoord[i], y: yCoord[i] };
        c.push(obj);
    }
        var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'None',
                    data: c,
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    borderColor: "#3e95cd",
                    fill: false,
                    cubicInterpolationMode: 'monotone'
                }
                ]
            },
            options: {
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: 'My Chart'
                },
                tooltips: {
                    mode: 'nearest',
                    intersect: true
                },
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        type: 'linear',
                        position: 'bottom',
                        scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: 'Year Assembly',
                            fontSize: 14
                                    }
                    }],
                    yAxes: [{
                        scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: 'Aquifer Values',
                            fontSize: 15
                                    }
                    }]
                }
            }
        });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var xCoord = new Array(1997, 2003, 2005, 2009, 2014, 2018, 2019);
    var yCoord = new Array(41, 31, 11, 31, 88, 101, 91);
    var c = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < xCoord.length; i++) {
        var obj = { x: xCoord[i], y: yCoord[i] };
        c.push(obj);
    }
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myTau').getContext('2d');
    var myTau = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            datasets: [{
                label: 'None',
                data: c,
                borderWidth: 1,
                borderColor: "#ef1414",
                fill: false,
                cubicInterpolationMode: 'monotone'
            }
            ]
        },
        options: {
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: 'My Chart 2'
            },
            tooltips: {
                mode: 'nearest',
                intersect: true
            },
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    type: 'linear',
                    position: 'bottom',
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: true,
                        labelString: 'Year Assembly',
                        fontSize: 14
                    }
                }],
                yAxes: [{
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: true,
                        labelString: 'Aquifer Values Corresponding',
                        fontSize: 15
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

**UPDATE:**

Here is another problem:

Is there any way to assign text position via chartjs coordinate system, in stead of "width., height."?

For instance, according to xCoord & yCoord arrays, is it possible to set the position of ctx.fillText x,y coordinates:

In stead of ctx.fillText("s(A)", width * .28, height * .70); can be like this : ctx.fillText("s(A)", 2005, 3); (2015,9) is belong to chartjs coordinate system.

My Aim:
s(A) can be seen on chartjs area at the point of (2005,3)
s(A) can be seen on chartjs area at the point of (2015,9)

[My Coordinate Problem Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvKMG.jpg)

Here is Last Problem Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="w3-row">
        <div class="w3-col s3"><p></p></div>
        <div class="w3-col s6" align="center"><canvas id="myChart" height="120"></canvas></div>
        <div class="w3-col s3"><p></p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-row">
        <div class="w3-col s3"><p></p></div>
        <div class="w3-col s6" align="center"><canvas id="myTau" height="120"></canvas></div>
        <div class="w3-col s3"><p></p></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var plugin = {
        beforeDraw: function (chart) {
            var width = chart.chart.width,
                height = chart.chart.height,
                ctx = chart.chart.ctx;
            ctx.restore();
            ctx.font = "1em sans-serif";
            ctx.textAlign = "center";
            ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
            ctx.fillText("s(A)", width * .28, height * .70);
            ctx.fillText("s(B)", width * .75, height * .55);
            //These section were set according to canvas width and height
            //I want to set coordinates chartjs coordinates like in data {x:1993,y:70}
             // Doesnt Work Like This: ctx.fillText("s(A)", 2005, 2);
             //Doesnt Work Like This: ctx.fillText("s(B)", 2015, 9);
            ctx.save();
        }
    };
    Chart.plugins.register(plugin);

    var xCoord = new Array(1997, 2003, 2005, 2009, 2014, 2018, 2019);
    var yCoord = new Array(1, 3, 5, 3, 6, 10, 9);
    var c = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < xCoord.length; i++) {
        var obj = { x: xCoord[i], y: yCoord[i] };
        c.push(obj);
    }
        var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'None',
                    data: c,
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    borderColor: "#3e95cd",
                    fill: false,
                    cubicInterpolationMode: 'monotone'
                }
                ]
            },
            options: {
                plugins: [plugin],
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: 'My Chart'
                },
                tooltips: {
                    mode: 'nearest',
                    intersect: true
                },
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        type: 'linear',
                        position: 'bottom',
                        scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: 'Year Assembly',
                            fontSize: 14
                                    }
                    }],
                    yAxes: [{
                        scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: 'Aquifer Values',
                            fontSize: 15
                                    }
                    }]
                }
            }
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### An working example:

```js
var plugin = {
  id: 'plugin',
  beforeDraw: function(chart) {

    var width = chart.chart.width,
      height = chart.chart.height,
      ctx = chart.chart.ctx,
      xScale = chart.scales['x-axis-0'],
      yScale = chart.scales['y-axis-0'];

    ctx.restore();
    ctx.font = "1em sans-serif";
    ctx.textAlign = "center";
    ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
    // ctx.fillText("s(A)", width * .28, height * .70);
    ctx.fillText(
      "s(A)",
      xScale.getPixelForValue('2005'),
      yScale.getPixelForValue(3)
    );
    ctx.fillText(
      "s(B)",
      xScale.getPixelForValue('2015'),
      yScale.getPixelForValue(9)
    );
    ctx.save();
  }
};

var xCoord = new Array(1997, 2003, 2005, 2009, 2014, 2018, 2019);
var yCoord = new Array(1, 3, 5, 3, 6, 10, 9);
var c = [];
for (var i = 0; i < xCoord.length; i++) {
  var obj = {
    x: xCoord[i],
    y: yCoord[i]
  };
  c.push(obj);
}
var ctx = document.getElementById('myTau').getContext('2d');
var myTau = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      label: 'None',
      data: c,
      borderWidth: 1,
      borderColor: "#ef1414",
      fill: false,
      cubicInterpolationMode: 'monotone'
    }]
  },
  plugins: [plugin],
  options: {
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'My Chart 2'
    },
    tooltips: {
      mode: 'nearest',
      intersect: true
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        type: 'linear',
        position: 'bottom',
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Year Assembly',
          fontSize: 14
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Aquifer Values Corresponding',
          fontSize: 15
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
var ctx = document.getElementById('myTax').getContext('2d');
var myTau = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      label: 'None',
      data: c,
      borderWidth: 1,
      borderColor: "#ef1414",
      fill: false,
      cubicInterpolationMode: 'monotone'
    }]
  },
  options: {
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'My Chart 2'
    },
    tooltips: {
      mode: 'nearest',
      intersect: true
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        type: 'linear',
        position: 'bottom',
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Year Assembly',
          fontSize: 14
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Aquifer Values Corresponding',
          fontSize: 15
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<canvas id="myTau" height="120"></canvas>
<canvas id="myTax" height="120"></canvas>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

Create and register a new `plugin` that draw the text, then call it only on the second chart, you can pass data as well (like an array of labels and the locations of each for example).

---

**Update:** (register plugins)

If you register a plugin globally then, you will have to disable the plugin in each chart here you don't want it to run.

```
options: {
    plugins: {
        plugin: false
    }
}
```

**- or -**

If you don't register the plugin globally, in each chart that you need to add the labels add the following:

```
{
    plugins: [plugin]
}
```

**Note:** In the second snippet of code `plugin` is not nested under `options`. Seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44371228/3376838).

---

**Update:** (display text using `x,y` datasets)

In order to use a `x,y` value you need to identify the axes you what the value from using its id, the defaults are `x-axis-0` and `y-axis-0`, that increments if you add more axes. Or use a custom axis id.

After that, within the `chart` instance there is a scale object that represents the axis and using `chart.scales['x-axis-0']` you can access a function called `getPixelForValue` which will convert the giving value from that axis to its pixel location.

Comment: When I attemped, this code is well done but in this problem, all charts is written.

Comment: @drakislow, I have updated my answer, please view the example again, and let me know the results.

Comment: The results are perfect. Thank you very much Sir.

Comment: Is there any way to manage text position via chartjs coordinate system, in stead of width., height.? @francisco-soares

Comment: @drakislow I don't think so, but please explain what exactly you want to achieve, maybe is possible to calculate the position in other way.

Comment: I've updated my issue @francisco-soares

Please check it.

Comment: @drakislow there is an way to get the pixel value from an axis value, take a look at the example again.

Comment: It's working on type of Line. If there is a scatter chart, can not work these codes. Is there any way to achieve with scatter chart?

For Example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bypjRv

Comment: @drakislow when using the scatter type the default id's start with `1`, so you have to change `x-axis-0` to `x-axis-1` and the same to the `y` axis.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="w3-row">
        <div class="w3-col s3"><p></p></div>
        <div class="w3-col s6" align="center"><canvas id="myChart" height="120"></canvas></div>
        <div class="w3-col s3"><p></p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-row">
        <div class="w3-col s3"><p></p></div>
        <div class="w3-col s6" align="center"><canvas id="myTau" height="120"></canvas></div>
        <div class="w3-col s3"><p></p></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var plugin = {
        beforeDraw: function (chart) {
            var width = chart.chart.width,
                height = chart.chart.height,
                ctx = chart.chart.ctx;
            ctx.restore();
            ctx.font = "1em sans-serif";
            ctx.textAlign = "center";
            ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
            ctx.fillText("s(A)", width * .28, height * .70);
            ctx.fillText("s(B)", width * .75, height * .55);
            ctx.save();
        }
    };
    Chart.plugins.register(plugin);

    var xCoord = new Array(1997, 2003, 2005, 2009, 2014, 2018, 2019);
    var yCoord = new Array(1, 3, 5, 3, 6, 10, 9);
    var c = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < xCoord.length; i++) {
        var obj = { x: xCoord[i], y: yCoord[i] };
        c.push(obj);
    }
        var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'None',
                    data: c,
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    borderColor: "#3e95cd",
                    fill: false,
                    cubicInterpolationMode: 'monotone'
                }
                ]
            },
            options: {
                plugins: [plugin],
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: 'My Chart'
                },
                tooltips: {
                    mode: 'nearest',
                    intersect: true
                },
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        type: 'linear',
                        position: 'bottom',
                        scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: 'Year Assembly',
                            fontSize: 14
                                    }
                    }],
                    yAxes: [{
                        scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: 'Aquifer Values',
                            fontSize: 15
                                    }
                    }]
                }
            }
        });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var xCoord = new Array(1997, 2003, 2005, 2009, 2014, 2018, 2019);
    var yCoord = new Array(41, 31, 11, 31, 88, 101, 91);
    var c = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < xCoord.length; i++) {
        var obj = { x: xCoord[i], y: yCoord[i] };
        c.push(obj);
    }
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myTau').getContext('2d');
    var myTau = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            datasets: [{
                label: 'None',
                data: c,
                borderWidth: 1,
                borderColor: "#ef1414",
                fill: false,
                cubicInterpolationMode: 'monotone'
            }
            ]
        },
        options: {
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: 'My Chart 2'
            },
            tooltips: {
                mode: 'nearest',
                intersect: true
            },
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    type: 'linear',
                    position: 'bottom',
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: true,
                        labelString: 'Year Assembly',
                        fontSize: 14
                    }
                }],
                yAxes: [{
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: true,
                        labelString: 'Aquifer Values Corresponding',
                        fontSize: 15
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Here is problem. The text is written all charts. My aim is only red one chart (My Chart 2).